# How do I depend on module for compile as well as test scope in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a module "A" which is depend on Module "common".  "common" module exposes methods in source.  It also exposes test utilities in test folder.
Source in module "A" is dependent on methods exposed by "common" as well as test classes in "A" is dependent on test utilities exposed by test folder in "common".
If I add dependency of "common" in pom.xml of "A" with scope as compile, then test classes in "A" cannot access test utils in "common".
How do I add dependency of "common" in "A" with compile as well as test scopes?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like these test utilities shouldn't be part of the `common` module. They should be in a separate module (maybe named `test-utils` or something like that). Other modules can then depend on `common` and/or `test-utils` independently and and set the appropriate scope for each dependency.